# Texture Painting brush size relative to world space instead of screen space?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to paint stitches on a model, similarly to how I do it in Substance Painter but using Blender Texture Paint mode.

How can I make sure my brush keep a size relative to the model instead of being the same size on the screen no matter how zoomed out or zoomed in I am relative to the model?[image]

Also, as another question, is it possible to paint normal details (not Bump) while painting a diffuse texture? I'd like my stitches to have some depth, so I did this normal map[image]

Comment: Apparently this is not implemented into Blender yet, I'll leave the question open though if someone has a cool trick...

Comment: Not possible yet - you ask about diffuse and normal at the same time, this is something they intend on making possible but it isn't here yet. Also, to get the detail there in color and normal might be more of a problem of using two images, one for the color and one for the normal and using them as array on a curve, and bake them to the maps on the main object. Work around that will always mean more work than might be necessary of course. Sculpting the detail and vertex paint bake could also be used, also a lot of work. Pablo is working on lots of sculpt and now paint, I am hopeful.

Comment: @CraigDJones Array and curves are cool for stitches I do use this technique sometimes since you can get the curves easily from edge loops, and yeah bake them in the normal map later but you'll never easily get the effect I have on the normal map here (the stretching of the fabric going downward). I never thought of using images and baking diffuse and normal from those, pretty cool concept. Sculpting and coloring after, for small details like that, no way haha.

Comment: To be clear - I mean to bake the images as texture to the main texture as color, and then switch up to the normal map array and bake to the color info of the normal map, so the same array on curve could be used for two different maps and use two different images.

Comment: Yep you would just select them along your high poly before baking from active, but I wonder if the baking would go that well with the normal data, since there is no alpha channel you'd need to somehow ignore the 100% 'flat' data on the normal to just get the stitch and not a massive flat square around it. Make sense? Or would this be automatic when baking?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing and getting weird results so far. If I get a working version, then I'll try to post.